# Removing Ignored Android Studio (or Intellij) Update Builds

Tags: android, intellij-idea, updates, android-studio

When an Android Studio update is posted and you mistakenly click on `Ignore This Update` how do you apply the update without having to reinstall Android Studio?

Comment: Sometime the Android Studio will recreate that option block.
So my solution is to change the itemvalue to another num.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Update**

As of the latest version of Android Studio, there is now a Preference in the UI [noted in an answer by Yogesh Umesh Vaity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999038/1373278)

**Original Answer**

The simple way to revert a mistaken choice is to close Android Studio then edit `other.xml` file and remove the `myIgnoredBuildNumbers` option block:

```xml
<option name="myIgnoredBuildNumbers">
  <value>
    <list size="1">
      <item index="0" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="130.729444" />
    </list>
  </value>
</option>
```

Technically you should edit the `size` and remove the `item` in question but after some testing the next time you ignore a build the `myIgnoredBuildNumbers` block will be rebuilt.

The `other.xml` file can be found at:

- OSX: `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/options/other.xml`
- WIN: `%HOMEPATH%\.AndroidStudio\config\options\other.xml`
- NIX: `~/.AndroidStudio/config/options/other.xml`

The same can be done in `Intellij` in the following paths:

- OSX: `~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC12/options/other.xml`
- WIN: `%HOMEPATH%\.IdeaIC12\options\other.xml`

As of Android Studio 1.2(possibly earlier), the ignored builds block is defined in updates.xml within the same directory as other.xml

Comment: Does anyone know the paths in *nix?

Comment: For Linux it's at `~/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/options/other.xml`.

Comment: Thanks I added that path. Need to install Intellij to be sure about it's path.

Comment: For Intellij14 on OSX this has been moved to `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14/options/updates.xml`

Comment: AndroidStudioPreview in the path is now just AndroidStudio

Comment: Excellent. Even this answer got official recommendation from Google too.[Android tools website](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel)

Answer (score 20):

There is an easier way to do this now. Android Studio has an option to delete the ignored updates in Preferences.

Go to:

```
Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > 
Updates > View/edit ignored updates
```

[image: Ignored Updates Android Studio]
A list of ignored updates will be opened. Just remove the updates that you don't want to ignore.
[image: Ignored Updates List Android Studio]

Answer (score 13):

**Updating hoss' answer:**

I have been using Android studio 1.4 on **Mac OSX** and happened to ignore update 1.5. The ignored build numbers are located in "updates.xml" at the following path.

> /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.4/options/**updates.xml**

Remove the "ignoredBuildNumbers" section from the updates.xml file and save it. Make sure you are updating the file in Android studio folder corresponding to version you are using. Another thing to note is, make sure you quit Android studio before updating the file. Else Studio will overwrite the xml file with previous data from memory. Edit the file and start Android studio again.

**Quit studio > Edit "updates.xml"> Start studio**

In case, that doesn't still work, switch to Canary channel and check for update. If there is an update, choose "Remind me later" option. Then switch back to STABLE channel and again check for update. It should be working now.

Comment: I had to remove these two lines in addition to ignoredbuildnumbers section. <option name="LAST_TIME_CHECKED" value="1449307380026" />
    <option name="LAST_BUILD_CHECKED" value="AI-141.2288178" />

Answer (score 3):

currently I'm using IDEA 14.0.4. I found the `myIgnoredBuildNumbers` option block in `"users/username/.IntelliJIdea14/config/options/updates.xml"`

Removing the entire  block and restarting will show the previously ignored release/build

```
  <option name="myIgnoredBuildNumbers">
       <value>
           <list size="1">
               <item index="0" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="141.713"/>
           </list>
       </value>
    </option>
```