# Android Studio update issue

Tags: android-studio

Currently running Android Studio 0.3.1 on a Mac. When I click "Check for updates" in the Canary Channel the message is that the latest version is installed, but this is not the case as the current version is already 0.4 +. Any ideas why it is not seeing the update (it prompted me yesterday to update but I did not) please?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474412/removing-ignored-android-studio-or-intellij-update-builds) and it's accepted answer. Could be that you selected **Ignore This Update** in which case it will not show up again (even when checking manually) until a new build is released.

Comment: @free3dom that was it, thanks! If you post that link as an answer I will accept.

Comment: My pleasure :) Will post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when you select **Ignore This Update** when prompted that an update is available.

The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474412/removing-ignored-android-studio-or-intellij-update-builds).