# Android Studio won't update says already on newest version

Tags: android-studio

When I try to 'Check for updates' in Android studio I get the following message:

"You already have the latest version of Android Studio (Preview) installed."

I am on 0.5.2 and the newest version listed here http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest is 0.5.4. I have canary builds selected when checking for updates. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Ignored Android Studio (or Intellij) Update Builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474412/removing-ignored-android-studio-or-intellij-update-builds)

Comment: Yes, thank you! This is the answer, I must have ignored and forgot I hit ignore. It might be a duplicate but it's probably still worthwhile leaving this one here as searching on the error message doesn't turn up anything in google.

Comment: Have had the same issue, and this post did help me in finding why it didn't work! I already knew about the ignored builds stuff and all, but haven't thought about it when I had this issue. Definitely posting it as an answer, as I think it could help some people!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Scott Barta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985303/scott-barta) has pointed out in a comment, this is because you have *ignored the update*, so it won't ask you if you want to update to it anymore.

The solution is simply to quit Android Studio, then edit its `other.xml` file, and replace the `myIgnoredBuildNumbers` block with the following one:

```
<option name="myIgnoredBuildNumbers">
  <value>
    <list size="0" />
  </value>
</option>
```

`other.xml` is located under your Android Studio config directory:

- For Unix: `~/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/options/other.xml`
- For Windows: `%HOMEPATH%\.AndroidStudioPreview\config\options\other.xml` (basically the same as the Unix path)
- For OS X: `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview/options/other.xml`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474412/removing-ignored-android-studio-or-intellij-update-builds) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17474413/1636285) for more information.

Comment: In more recent versions, this setting seems to have been moved to updates.xml in the same folder as other.xml.

Comment: Possible. I haven't verified this because I haven't had this issue recently, but feel free to edit that into the post.

Comment: newer version has a "View ignored updates" when you receive this "already have latest" popup (at the bottom of it), just clean/remove the versions in the list and try again \o/

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences > Updates and clear out the versions listed in the View/edit ignored updates section:

[image]