# android studio not updating to 3.0 version from 2.3 version

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to Upgrade my android studio 2.3 to 3.0 (Linux user)

Inadvertently I pressed "Ignore this update" message.
Then I googled and found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23636941/5078003)

As it saying I Edited my other.xml file in

`~/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/options/other.xml`

Tried to update again after edited **other.xml** file.It showed some message as download finished.

But still my studio is not upgraded to 3.0 from 2.3

Have idea to solve it.
thank you .

Comment: find your .AndroidStudio2.3 folder inside user folder and delete it .. also delete .gradle folder inside user folder.. Note: First Close Your android studio and then do it.. after delete open your android studio again and then update 3.o

Comment: @JJG Thanks it is working. But a new android studio of version 3.0 beta 6 is downloaded instead overwrite or update on existing one(version 2.3).

Comment: Because Current Release is android Studio 3.0 beta .. read this for more detail https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your **.AndroidStudio2.3** folder inside **user** folder and delete it .. also delete **.gradle** folder inside **user** folder..

**Note: First Close Your android studio and then do it.. after delete open your android studio again and then update 3.0**