# Android studio not updating from 3.0 to 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-update-app

I am using Android studio **3.0**, Android studio give a dialog to update Android studio **3.0.1**

When i click on update link it show a dialog 


[image: update dialog screen]

I click on update and restart button after downloading Android studio restart but the new updated version not showing and again android studio give update dialog for updating to 3.0.1 version.


it is happens many times.

Anybody knows whats goes worng.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46254072/3395198

Comment: If you need latest version and have time simply download latest version from official page https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html. Kindly visit this link with your working system so it will pick best latest version package based on your system configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following way:

1. File > Close Project. Close AndroidStudio.
2. restart AndroidStudio, it will not open any project and show you a project list, **don't open any project**.
3. wait for AndroidStudio to popup a dialog to remind you there is a new version.
4. click **update & restart**.
5. after restart, it may remind you import previous configuration files.
6. import configuration, open a project, you will see the new version number.

Comment: Not working for me updating Studio 3.4 to 3.4.2 on windows