# Android studio update not showings

Tags: android-studio

I have Android studio version 1.5.1 in my mac OS. Latest version available in market is 2.0 as per http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0

[image]

When i try to update, it shows me following alert.

[image]

It shows that i have latest version installed. Any idea what may have cause this bug? Do i need to download whole new setup?

I have tried by invalidating cache and restarting studio but no luck.

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you have *ignored the update*, so it won't ask you if you want to update to it anymore.

The solution is simply to quit Android Studio, then edit its `other.xml` file, and replace the `myIgnoredBuildNumbers` block with the following one:

```
<option name="myIgnoredBuildNumbers">
  <value>
    <list size="0" />
  </value>
</option>
```

`other.xml` is located under your Android Studio config directory:

- For Unix: `~/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/options/other.xml`
- For Windows: `%HOMEPATH%\.AndroidStudioPreview\config\options\other.xml` (basically the same as the Unix path)
- For OS X: `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview/options/other.xml`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474412/removing-ignored-android-studio-or-intellij-update-builds) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17474413/1636285) for more information.

Comment: Current version is stable version

Comment: @Beena visit this it may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133518/how-to-update-android-studio-automatically

Comment: I had tried by changing it to dev and now able to see pop up. Thanks

Comment: Stable version is available. Still it not showing updates for stable version.