# Remove ignored Android Studio update

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have the 2.2.3 version of Android Studio on Ubuntu and I clicked "Ignore this update" by mistake. How can I apply the update without having to reinstall Android Studio?

I found the answer below, but I can't find the other.xml neither updates.xml files:
[Removing Ignored Android Studio (or Intellij) Update Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474412/removing-ignored-android-studio-or-intellij-update-builds)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Ignored Android Studio (or Intellij) Update Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474412/removing-ignored-android-studio-or-intellij-update-builds)

Answer (score 5):

In Linux go to `~/.AndroidStudio2.2/config/options` folder and edit `updates.xml`.

Remove `ignoredBuildNumbers` block.

In my updates.xml file, it was like below. Removing this block solved it.

```
<ignoredBuildNumbers>
    <item value="162.3764568" />
</ignoredBuildNumbers>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention, this should be done with android studio stopped.

Answer (score 4):

On my MacOS it was present on :

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/updates.xml
```

And I removed the following lines

```
<ignoredBuildNumbers>
   <item value="162.3764568" />
</ignoredBuildNumbers>
```

Comment: I just removed the `<item />` entry, not the whole `<ignoredBuildNumbers>`.